# breeze Copy lower triangle not working?

Tags: scala, breeze

Using breeze 0.13, Scala 2.12.3

I would like to create a symmetric matrix by copying the lower triangle to the upper one. Following the instructions in [Linear Algebra Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet). May be I use the function incorrectly but it seems like the `lowerTriangular` function is not working correctly. The copy just

```
val myMtx = breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix((1,-8,-9) , (2,1,-7), (3,5,1))
//myMtx: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] = 
//  1  -8  -9
//  2   1  -7
//  3   5   1
```

Copy lower triangle (seems not working)

```
breeze.linalg.lowerTriangular(myMtx)
//  1  0  0
//  2  1  0
//  3  5  1
```

Copy upper triangle (not working either)

```
breeze.linalg.upperTriangular(myMtx)
//  1  -8  -9
//  0   1  -7
//  0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "copy" means returns the matrix in a newly allocated memory.  This is contrast with a "view" that indexes into the same backing memory.

With that in mind, both lowerTriangular and upperTriangular seem to be working properly in that it returns a new matrix that has the same elements copied from the original matrix.

The task is now to create a new symmetric matrix that is the copy of the lower triangular.  One possible way is to compute the element-wise sum of the lower and lower diagonal transpose, and then subtract the extra copy of the diagonal that was computed.  The inner diag() returns a view, as described above, as a vector and that vector is then used to create a diagonal matrix with the second diag().

```
@ val sym = lowerTriangular(myMtx) + lowerTriangular(myMtx).t - diag(diag(myMtx)) 
sym: DenseMatrix[Int] = 
1  2  3  
2  1  5  
3  5  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the definition of lowerTriangular and upperTriangular. Like very much the trick with `diag(diag(myMtx))`